# What's wrong with embark gas limit?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, embark

I have a problem using Embark to deploy a contract.

I have successfully use it before with smaller contracts.

Here is the problem hint:

> contract was deployed at 0xc9f10a4696f4102d0ef3ec4ce5eb5426828a1b06
>   but doesn't seem to be working try adjusting your gas values

The contract is deployed, but all functions in it **can not** be called?

How to solve this problem?

Comment: I don't see how this is a programming question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes, when the contract have a problem (with constructor, for instance), the transaction to create it consumes all the available gas (gas limit) and then, you end up with no contract and all gas spent.

Check if the contract has no errors (not only compile-time, but runtime too). See if it runs fine on a javascriptVM (try use this guy: https://github.com/ethereum/browser-solidity).

Try using a parameterless constructor, or even a constructorless contract.